# how to take a lambda function as an input

Tags: python, lambda

the separate function takes a function and list and return two list, my question is how to translate the following function to the lambda input to make my separate function work? (the first input in my separate function is incorrect, it raise a syntax error)

```
def function(x:list):
    for y in x:
        if y > x[0]:
            return True
        else:
            return False

separate(lambda x: for y in x: y > x[0], l):
```

Comment: can you provide some definition of separate function...what is so far you have tried when creating the separate function?

Comment: actually, it doesn't matter, my question is only about the lambda function.

Comment: Why can't you use ```separate(function(x))```?

Comment: I just want to translate the function to the lambda function for the input, since mine raised a syntax error.

Comment: because I can not define another function, it is the requirement.

Comment: I don't get a syntax error for your function - are you using Python 2.x??

Comment: no, I am using 3.5

Comment: ```I can not define another function, it is the requirement``` - lambda's are functions try ```type(lambda x: True)```

Comment: I mean I can not define another function outside of this separate function and call that function. I can only define the lambda function as it shows in my input. I just want to find a way to fix it.

Comment: K sorry - It looks like you are always comparing ```x[0]``` with the first element in ```x``` which is itself - then you immediately return - is that what  it is supposed to do?

Comment: I am actually comparing every element in the x with the first element which is x[0]. and return a bool if it is bigger than x[0] or not.  I just want to translate this function to a lambda but it raise an error.

Comment: You return a bool for every element in the list?

Comment: yes, that is the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
separate(lambda x: map(lambda y : y > x[0], x))
```

Which returns a map object

```
>>> 
>>> z = lambda x: map(lambda y : y > x[0], x)
>>> list(z([1,2,3]))
[False, True, True]
>>> list(z([10, 2, 3, 11, 9]))
[False, False, False, True, False]
>>>
```

---

The *outer* lambda takes the list as its input (`x`) and returns the result of `map`. The second lambda is mapped over the elements of x - `map` provides the iteration.

---

Or just use a list comprehension

```
separate(lambda x: [y > x[0] for y in x])

>>> z = lambda x: [y > x[0] for y in x]
>>> list(z([10, 2, 3, 11, 9]))
[False, False, False, True, False]
>>>
```

---

Unwrap the list comprehension to a regular function definition to compare with  `function` in your post

```
def function(x:list):
    result = []
    for y in x:
        result.append(y > x[0])
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example function taking a lambda function.

```
def myNewFilter(x, lst):
    return filter(x, lst)

startingWithX = lambda x: x.startswith('X')

lst = ['Xa', 'Xb', 'a', 'b']
print myNewFilter(startingWithX, lst)
```

Output:

```
['Xa', 'Xb']
```

Comment: ok, but this does not quite answer my question, since I cannot define another function. I can only define the lambda function as the way it shows in my separate function.

Comment: you either have to define the lambda function inline, or give it a name...those are the only two options..